# How to use XORShift algorithm to generate random numbers

Tags: algorithm, random

How to use XORShift algorithm to generate **96-bit** random numbers. After run the application, each time I press "Start Button" it returns a different 96-bit number.

Code for XORShift algorithm:

```
unsigned long xor()
{
  static unsigned long y=2463534242;
  yˆ=(y<<13); y=(y>>17); 
  return (yˆ=(y<<5)); 
}
```

Comment: If it's a random number generator, isn't that what it's supposed to do?

Comment: randomnumber generators usually use the systemtime as seed. Thus the algorithm will return different results for different times. Though without any code it's difficult to tell where the problem is

Comment: Yes, please show some code. This is an interesting topic, but without code it's impossible to have a discussion (I didn't downvote). I'm guessing @Paul is right though.

Comment: You need to specify also the repeat rate.  I can easily generate a random 96 bit number that repeats every 4th number.

Comment: @jdweng I want long period

Comment: @Paul I have put the code

Comment: See wikli https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift.  Using a prime number for the seed increases the period of the repeat cycle.  The repeat cycle is a function of the factors of the seed.  So having a seed with no factors is the best seed.  Mathematicians have been studying prime number and methods for calculating prime just for this purpose.

Comment: @SHdotCom there is still a detail missing: the initial values of `a b c x y z w`.

Comment: @Paul please check the code.

Comment: There is a bug in the paper of George Marsaglia. The second assignment must be this: `y ^= y >> 17`. The circumflex is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is supposed to result in a different value for each run. Since `y` is `static`, it's value is initially 2463534242. But due to the `static` keyword, the value will remain in memory, until the program terminates (this is a bit of a simplified explanation, but it should do for this problem). So after the first run of the program, the value of `y` is the same as the result of `xor()`. This `y` is the initial value of `y` (the seed), when `xor()` is called for the next time, thus `xor()` produces a different value in the next run.

Answer (score 0):

If i had to guess: you don't reset the value of `a`, `b`, `c`, `x`, etc. after running the algorithm. Thus the algorithm will use different initial values for each run, resulting in the observed behavior.

Comment: how to make it returns a 96-bit number?

Comment: you'll have to use a char[] for this purpose, since c++ doesn't support 96 bit numbers

Comment: what about Delphi language?

Comment: as far as i know, delphi doesn't support these aswell. You could either use Pascal - only language i know with arbitrary value range - or a library for c++. Though since you're only using shifting it shouldn't be too hard to implement this